# How do you select a CSS class in Scriptaculous JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<div class="myclass" id="demo" style="display:none;">Hello.</div>

<a href="#" onclick="$('.myclass').fade({ duration: 0.3, from: 1, to: 0 }); $('demo').appear({ delay: 0.35 }); return false;">Click ME!</a><br />
```

My Firebug development plugin says:

> $(".myclass") is null

I have tried various other names, such as: `$('div.myclass')` and `$('myclass')`, to no avail. How do I get this effect to work on a class? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$$('.myclass')[0].fade()
```

$$ in prototype (and mootools) accepts any sort of css selector like $`$('div#joe')` or $`$('a[rel=awesome]')` and returns an array.

$ will return just an element with a matching id like $('joe');

So given this html:

```
<div id="joe" class="awesome"></div>
<div id="sally" class="awesome"></div>
```

1. `$$('.awesome')` will return an array containing both DIVs
2. `$('joe')` and `$$('#joe')` are effectually the same (though the latter is an array).

---

**EDIT**

First remove your onclick events and add some information to the rel attribute like so:

```
<a rel="demo" href="#">Div 1</a><br />
<a rel="demo2" href="#">Div 2</a><br />
<a rel="demo3" href="#">Div 3</a>
```

Then put this in the `head` of your document in a script tag.

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    // this makes sure the document is loaded and ready to be manipulated       

    // store your links and demo DIVs in arrays
    var links = $$('div.rightcol a');
    var demos = $$('.myclass');

    // enumerate over the links
    links.each(function(link){
        // observe the click event of the current link in the loop
        link.observe('click',function(event){
            event.stop();
            // loop the demo DIVs and fade each one
            demos.each(function(demo){
                demo.fade({ duration: 0.3, from: 1, to: 0 });
            });
            // figure out which demo to fade in from the links rel attribute
            var target = link.readAttribute('rel');
            // get the demo target and fade it in
            $(target).appear({ delay: 0.35 });
        });
    });

});
```

I hope the script is easy to follow.

Comment: Now firbug says says: $$(".myclass").fade is not a function

Comment: See the edit to the first line, that's now pointing the first element of the returned elements from $$, in your case it should only be one.

Comment: Thanks much for your help thus far. I still can't get the class selector to work however. Getting the "not a function" error. I want to fade more divs than just that one. Here's the page I'm working on:

http://www.linksband.com/new

Answer (score 1):

To credit rpflo it is not ideal to use obtrusive javascript. However if you are looking for the simplest code to insert you can always use the invoke method which is provided by Prototype.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$$('.myclass').invoke('fade',{ duration: 0.1, from: 1, to: 0 });
$$('.myclass').invoke('appear',{ delay: 0.35 });return false;">Div 1</a>
```

The invoke method performs the same function on set of DOM elements and avoids having to use the .each() method.

Comment: Very good to know.  Mootools is my javascript home and it "invokes" automatically if you've got $$('.blah').fade().  Using each still probably makes sense so when you've got to do more than one thing per loop, instead of $$('.class').invoke('whatever').invoke('something').invoke('blah');

Comment: Wait a sec ... your code fades them all out, then fades them all in again.  When "Div 1" is clicked only div#demo should appear.  You'd want to change that to just $('demo').appear([args]); for the first link, and then demo2 and demo3 for the next two.